# check username availability via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I want to check if username is available via ajax. I currently am using the following code:

HTML

```
<div id="registration-form">
  <label for="username">Enter Username :
  <input name="username" type="text" id="username" maxlength="15"> <span id="user-result"></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var x_timer;    
    $("#username").keyup(function (e){
        clearTimeout(x_timer);
        var user_name = $(this).val();
        x_timer = setTimeout(function(){
            check_username_ajax(user_name);
        }, 1000);
    }); 

function check_username_ajax(username){
    $("#user-result").html('<img src="ajax-loader.gif" />');
    $.post('username-checker.php', {'username':username}, function(data) {
      $("#user-result").html(data);
    });
}
});
</script>
```

and here is php

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["username"]))
{
    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {
        die();
    }
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost' , 'root', 'juaid123', 'project2');
    if ($mysqli->connect_error){
        die('Could not connect to database!');
    }

    $username = filter_var($_POST["username"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW|FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);

    $statement = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT username FROM user_list WHERE username=?");
    $statement->bind_param('s', $username);
    $statement->execute();
    $statement->bind_result($username);
    if($statement->fetch()){
        die('Username Not Available!');
    }else{
        die('Username Available!');
    }
}
?>
```

Everything work perfectly and my code show message in real time, but problem is i don't want to show any message if username characters  is less then 6 and only want to allow letters and number in input field, can you please help me how i can do this..
Thanks

Comment: you should also use a serverside method as a *Plan-B*, should they disable JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use the HTML pattern attribute on your input to limit only numbers and letters http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp. `[a-zA-Z0-9]`

Then you can just put a validation in your post function:

```
$("#username").keyup(function (e){
    clearTimeout(x_timer);
    var user_name = $(this).val();
    if(user_name.length >= 6){  //Validate number of characters here
        x_timer = setTimeout(function(){
            check_username_ajax(user_name);
        }, 1000);
    }
});
```

Comment: You got it! No problem